# How to create a table of tables?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a situation when we need to create a table of tables, e.g.,
for

```
Tablei[i_] = Table[{a[i,j], b[i,j]},{j,0,LargeNumber,1}]
```

Create

```
Tabletotal = Join[Tablei[1],Tablei[2],...Tablei[OtherLargeNumber]]
```

But this is annoying for large `OtherLargeNumber`. Could you please tell me how to do this iteratively, i.e. something like using cycle, or some built-in command, with some function `TableI[OtherLargeNumber]`?

Comment: `Table[Tablei[k],{k,1,OtherLargeNumber}]`. Or just `Table[{a[i,j], b[i,j]},{j,0,LargeNumber,1},{i,1,OtherLargeNumber}]` in one go.

Comment: @corey979 : the first table is not in the form of two columns, but in a form of one large row with tables.

Comment: Add `Flatten[....,1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Original Method

```
tables[n1_, n2_] := Join @@ Table[{a[i, j], b[i, j]}, {i, n2}, {j, 0, n1}]
Short@tables[100, 100]
```

> {{a[1,0],b[1,0]},{a[1,1],b[1,1]},<<10097>>,{a[100,100],b[100,100]}}

### Other Methods

And a comparison of a few other ways that are albeit surprisingly slower, but also get the job done.  Also a good example at the optimization of `Table`.

```
 With[
  {n = 10},
  SameQ[
   Join @@ Table[{a[i, j], b[i, j]}, {i, n}, {j, 0, n}],
   {a@##, b@##} & @@@ Tuples@Range[{1, 0}, {n, n}],
   Replace[Tuples@Range[{1, 0}, {n, n}], {x__} :> {a[x], b[x]}, 1],
   Tuples@Range[{1, 0}, {n, n}] /. {x__Integer} :> {a[x], b[x]},
   Join @@ Array[{a@##, b@##} &, {n, n + 1}, {1, 0}]
  ]
]
```

> True

```
DiscretePlot[
 {
  AbsoluteTiming[Join @@ Table[{a[i, j], b[i, j]}, {i, n}, {j, 0, n}]][[1]],
  AbsoluteTiming[Join @@ Array[{a@##, b@##} &, {n, n + 1}, {1, 0}]][[1]],
  AbsoluteTiming[{a@##, b@##} & @@@ Tuples@Range[{1, 0}, {n, n}]][[1]],
  AbsoluteTiming[Replace[Tuples@Range[{1, 0}, {n, n}], {x__} :> {a[x], b[x]}, 1]][[1]],
  AbsoluteTiming[Tuples@Range[{1, 0}, {n, n}] /. {x__Integer} :> {a[x], b[x]}][[1]]
 },
 {n, 1, 501, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"List Length (n)", "Timing (s)"},
 Joined -> True,
 Filling -> None,
 PlotLegends -> {"Table", "Array", "Apply", "Replace", "ReplaceAll"},
 PlotLabel -> "Method Timing Comparison \r",
 ImageSize -> Large,
 BaseStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> Times}
]
```

[image]

I was surprised because the creation of the index list using `Tuples` was much faster than creating the same list with `Table` (by **at least** an order of magnitude), but the subsequent either application or replacement ended up making it much slower than just using `Table[{a[i, j], b[i, j]},...]` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly what you actually need is

```
Table[{a[i,j], b[i,j]},{j,LargeNumber},{i,AnoutherLargeNumber}]
```